# Metaprogramming examples in F#

Tags: .net, f#, metaprogramming

I'm interested in metaprogramming examples written in F# that demonstrate the use of F#-specific functionality such as the [`TryGetReflectedDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340247.aspx) function in the F# standard library.

Where might I find such examples?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[WebSharper](https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper) and [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/) are two examples of open source F# libraries using Quotations (Unquote doesn't specifically use `TryGetReflectedDefinition`, but I believe WebSharper does).

[FSharp.PowerPack.Linq](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/tree/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack.Linq) is another example. Also, I've found the [implementation of quotations](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs) in the F# compiler to be a helpful and insightful reference.

Comment: I develop WebSharper, and yes, we use quotations metadata. Although we had to rewrite TryGetReflectedDefinition to work around some F# bugs, we are using the same metadata tables as this function.

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago, I wrote a project that translates F# quotations to GPU code using [MSR Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/).

This is a fairly simple translator (compared e.g. to WebSharper, which is pretty complex), but it should demonstrate most of the features you're interested in. In particular, it translates functions marked with the `ReflectedDefinition` attribute. It is also from your favorite scientific computing domain :-)

- [Accelerator and F# (III.): Data-parallel programs using F# quotations](http://tomasp.net/articles/accelerator-dataparallel.aspx)
- [Accelerator and F# (IV.): Composing computations with quotations](http://tomasp.net/blog/accelerator-quotations.aspx)